# Do sfSubForm.fForm.RecordSource and Forms(fForm).RecordSource refer to the same object and property?

Tags: ms-access, vba

this has me pretty confused and I can't find the answer anywhere else so thought I'd post here to see if anyone can help!

I have a form in an Access 2007 database with a subform (sfSubform) embedded in it.  The subform control's SourceObject is set to be another form (fForm).  fForm's RecordSource starts out as a table.

At one point I want to change the data displayed in the subform to the result of a SQL statement, so I use

```
 sfSubform.Form.RecordSource = strSQL.
```

This works fine.  However, if I ouput the name of the RecordSource for fForm after making this change, it still gives the name of the table that I orginially set.

Does sfSubform.Form.RecordSource not change the source of fForm?  Is it a copy of fForm that is embedded in the control?

Hope all that makes sense.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. A subform is an instance of a form. Changes to its properties at runtime are not persisted unless you explicitly save those changes. This is desirable behavior, in fact.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise the forms produced at runtime were instances of the form earlier designed.  Thanks, that makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The sub-form and the form each have their own record source (or are unbound).  That's the whole point, actually -- the ability to present two different data sets.  Typically the two forms have related record sources and this relationship is declared using Master/Child Link, but that also is optional according to the need.

So no, changing one won't cause the other to be changed.